# Calculate movement (var_t0 - var_t1) for n numbers of columns in a wide-formatted dataset in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I was wondering if there's a neat way (probably a loop) for the task I have. First of all, my data are structured more or less like this:

```
MyData<-data.frame("date"=c(2006,2006,2006,2010,2010,2010,2014,2014,2014),
                "party"=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                "value_1"=c(sample(1:100,9,rep=T)),
                "value_2"=c(sample(1:100,9,rep=T)),
                "value_k"=c(sample(1:100,9,rep=T)))
```

Now what I need is the movement of each political party in "value" from one point in time to the next (e.g. party A's movement from 2006 to 2010 = ?). To this end, I reshaped my data:

```
MyData_wide <- reshape(MyData, direction = "wide", timevar = "date", idvar = c("party"))
```

So to get the parties' movement from one year to the next, I would simply subtract like this:

```
MyData_wide$move_val1_0610 <- MyData_wide$value1.2006 - MyData_wide$value1.2010
```

Now suppose that I have k of these "value"-variables. Is there a way I can use a for()-loop to calculate these movements faster?

What I would like to tell R is "for every pair of value variables, take the latter and subtract it from the former and for each of these subtractions, create a new variable in MyData_wide that looks like .$move_val1_0610"

Answer (score 1):

Use double brackets for assignment of new columns, and use `paste` to name them:

```
for (i in c("1", "2", "k")) {
    MyData_wide[[paste0("newvar",i)]] <- 
        MyData_wide[[paste0("value_",i,".2006")]] -  
        MyData_wide[[paste0("value_",i,".2010")]]
}
```

You'll need to be creative in your looping to do the "for every pair of value variables" part.  I would suggest using a year variable, let's call it `y`, and selecting variables with `y` and `y+4` in the names:

```
MyData_wide[[paste0("value_",i,".",y)]] - MyData_wide[[paste0("value_",i,".",y+4)]]
```

Comment: I got the first part and it's working. Thank you! But I'm not quite sure about the second part, especially because the date variable is not in equal intervals of 4 years (which I should have mentioned in the beginning). But do you think it would work to tell R "take column k, then take column k+1 and subtract k+1 from k"?

Comment: Second question: not only do I have a bunch of years in "date" but I have even more "value" variables. Does that mean I have to type every value-suffix into the first line like this "for (i in c("1","2","3","4","5","6","...")) {..."?

Comment: Re 1) Sure, if your data are structured so that those are the cols you want to difference, then that should work.

Comment: Re 2) use something simpler like `1:8`.  I had to put quotes because your example had 1, 2, k (and k is not numeric).

Comment: Re Re 1) How would one do that?

Comment: Can you post a new SO question with example data and your code so far?  Then I (and others) can take a look.  Once you've posted the question, tag my username in a comment so that I get a notification.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to arrange your data in a list, then do something like this

```
set.seed(1234L) # For reproducibility
MyData<-data.frame("date"=c(2006,2006,2006,2010,2010,2010,2014,2014,2014),
                   "party"=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                   "value_1"=c(sample(1:100,9,rep=T)),
                   "value_2"=c(sample(1:100,9,rep=T)),
                   "value_k"=c(sample(1:100,9,rep=T)))
MyData
  date party value_1 value_2 value_k
1 2006     A      12      52      19
2 2006     B      63      70      24
3 2006     C      61      55      32
4 2010     A      63      29      31
5 2010     B      87      93      16
6 2010     C      65      30       4
7 2014     A       1      84      22
8 2014     B      24      29      82
9 2014     C      67      27      53

temp <- split(MyData, MyData$party) #converting into a list with respect to variable party

temp
$A
  date party value_1 value_2 value_k
1 2006     A      12      52      19
4 2010     A      63      29      31
7 2014     A       1      84      22

$B
  date party value_1 value_2 value_k
2 2006     B      63      70      24
5 2010     B      87      93      16
8 2014     B      24      29      82

$C
  date party value_1 value_2 value_k
3 2006     C      61      55      32
6 2010     C      65      30       4
9 2014     C      67      27      53

foo <- function(x) {apply(x[,3:5], MARGIN = 2,FUN = diff)} # function to compute the 1 lag difference in columns 3 4 and 5 of a data.frame x
res <- lapply(temp, foo) # applying foo to each element of temp

res
$A
  value_1 value_2 value_k
4      51     -23      12
7     -62      55      -9

$B
  value_1 value_2 value_k
5      24      23      -8
8     -63     -64      66

$C
  value_1 value_2 value_k
6       4     -25     -28
9       2      -3      49
```

Comment: It looks really nice, but I don't really understand what it is doing. What does "-38" for "value_1" in row "4" tell me? It is obviously not "6-97"...

Comment: We haven't obtained the same results because your sample an mine were different. Now I edited to fix the sample (`set.seed`) and adding some lines and comments to clarify my solution.

Comment: Nice, thank you. But 1) is there a way to incorporate "res" back into the list (as new columns [including NA's for each party's first row obviously]) and reshape that list back into my original data frame?

Comment: 2) Would there be a way to tell that function to only take a column for subtraction if its value is >50? So for instant "only calculate difference for B for value_k from 2010 to 2014 (leaving 2006 to 2010 aside).

Comment: Re1. You can try something like `do.call(rbind,res)`. I also figured out another way to obtain this result directly from `MyData` using `data.table`: `setDT(MyData)[,.(difdate=date[2:3], difval_1= diff(value_1), difval_2=diff(value_2), difval_k=diff(value_k) ),by=party]`. For details on `data.table` check on [https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf]

Comment: Genius! But why is this working? If I check `MyData$date[2:3]`, the outcome is `[1] 2006 2006` cause they are the first two rows of `date`. But obviously your line of code calculates the movements for `2006`to `2010`to `2014` just as it should...

Comment: The thing is that when you are doing just `MyData@date[2:3]` you are taking your original `MyData`, so you are taking the column `date` as is. On the other hand, when I'm `setDT`ing `MyData` and adding the argument `by=party`, all the procedures are computed by `party` variable. Also, what `diff` function actually do is take the difference between subsequent observations (second minus first, third minus second, and so on) so when I'm computing `difdate=date[2:3]` is just to conserve the 2010 and 2014 in `date` (excluding the first one because its difference will not be defined).

Comment: Is also very import to mention that this will work only if the `date` is sorted increasingly with respect to each party.

Comment: `setDT` is not sorting, I just used your dataset which was sorted as it was given. To order your data you can try `MyData <- MyData[order(MyData$party, MyData$date),]`